# Dynamics CRM 2013 cascade delete does not fire children plugin

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a parent entity A that has 3 children entities B,C & D. I have registered plugins on Delete on each of the entities with event pipeline "PreValidation". Inside CRM I have set the cascade delete to all from parent A to all children. My issue is when a delete occurs on Parent the plugins registered on the children do not fire.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve the issue by adding code inside the parent plugin to capture data from deleted children as I know they will be deleted through cascade.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are doing depth check and returning if it is greater than one.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).